# Debugging the Facebook crawler for share button

Tags: facebook, button, share

I'm trying to debug/troubleshoot why the content that is displayed in the share link/window continues to show our browser detection content which we do not want displayed. I've updated our code to detect the Facebook crawler and *not* show this content if it's detected but the share link is still showing this. I've even tried to use the Facebook debugger to refresh the cache but it is still not working.

The share button code I'm using is this:

```
<div class="fb-like"
 data-href="https://www-dev.hoopladigital.com/title/11042831"
 data-layout="button_count"
 data-colorscheme="dark"
 data-action="like"
 data-show-faces="true"
 data-share="true"></div>
```

So either the cache is not being cleared, or my browser detection code is still getting executed when it shouldn't be. The text pointed to in the arrow in this screenshot should not be getting displayed.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

http://note.io/LvbN5K

Comment: Your `og:description` is _empty_, so most likely Facebook takes the first text content that looks relevant to it … so provide a description!

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant! Thank you, that resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your `og:description` is *empty*, so most likely Facebook takes the first text content that looks relevant to it … so provide a description!